# Binding not working when we use ListView with DataTemplate through Resources.(MVVM)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a `ListView` which gets its `ItemTemplate` from a Resource file.

I have a Resource dictionary as below!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         xmlns:common="clr-namespace:xx.Common;assembly=xx"
         x:Class="xx.ResourceDictionaries.BaseHomeStyles"> 

 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid Padding="{StaticResource ListPadding}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" Aspect="Fill" DownsampleToViewSize="True" BitmapOptimizations="True"
                                            ErrorPlaceholder = "nopreviewlandscape" LoadingPlaceholder = "loadingicon" Source="{Binding TripImage}" />
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TripName}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="downarrow" Rotation="-90" BackgroundColor="{Binding PrimaryColor}"/>
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding ReferenceNumber}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding TripUIStartDate}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding DaysDetails}" TextColor="{StaticResource AppQuaternaryBackground}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <!--<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ToItineraryCommand, Source={x:Reference HomeList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>-->
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I use this `DataTemplate` as the `ItemTemplate` something like this:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows = "true" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTripInfo}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
       CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" x:Name="HomeList" SeparatorVisibility ="Default" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" />
```

I am adding this ResourceDictionary something like this :

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <resources:BaseHomeStyles/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Now what I am trying to do here is setting a Click `Command` in my `ViewModel`,
Usually, how I did that was setting a name to the `ListView` as I have in the above example and then use this name to get the List's `BindingContext` and then use this to set the command to it, but when I try to use this now it throws an XML parser exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 38:43. Can not find the object referenced by `HomeList`

Now I have two questions:

1- What is the correct way of setting a command to the ListView when doing it the above way?

2- If in the future I plan on moving this to App.XAML(if used multiple times) how can I set the command to it then?

Comment: You can check this post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776976/how-do-i-bind-datatemplate-in-a-resource-dictionary

Comment: How set are you on using the DataTemplate in a resource dictionary opposed to a custom viewcell? Anyway this might be an interesting read: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96459/xamarin-forms-parent-bindingcontext-in-datatemplate-in-the-xaml

Comment: @Knoop Thanks but I like the behavior solution better

Comment: @G.hakim No problem, just thinking about some alternatives. I understand in this case it's a decision between cleaner but situation specific vs more generic/extensible but less clean. And that is a decision that will differ from project to project, so only you can make that one. Anyway good luck with the project!

Comment: @Knoop Thank you anyway, brother, I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the misleading link, I understood your problem just now.

You could use the ListView Behaviors to solve your problem, it's so fancy and easier to reader than bind the command on the code behind.

You could follow the link below to see how it's done, and later make it better just converting all the behaviors into only one and passing a event name to it, looking for the event with `GetRuntimeEvent(eventName)` and `AddEventHandler()` on the object that the last method returns.

In the end your list view would look something like this:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows = "true" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTripInfo}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
       CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" x:Name="HomeList" SeparatorVisibility ="Default" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" >
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommand EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/

Comment: Thanks, but I would suggest you add the relevant bits from the link in your answer, as the link might become invalid in the future!